# Mongoose - Group get only one

Tags: mongoose

I have a collection of users each with a sanction list:

```
{
    _id: ...
    user: 'username',
    sanctions: [
        {
            type: 'MUTE',
            expiry: 'ISODate("2021-02-15T17:00:38.461Z")'
        },
        {
            type: 'MUTE',
            expiry: 'ISODate("2021-10-15T17:00:38.461Z")'
        },
        {
            type: 'WARN',
            expiry: 'ISODate("2021-10-15T17:00:38.461Z")'
        }
    ]
},
{
    _id: ...
    user: 'username1',
    sanctions: [
        {
            type: 'MUTE',
            expiry: 'ISODate("2021-10-20T17:00:38.461Z")'
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to retrieve all the most recent user mutes.
I tried that:

```
await User.aggregate([
            { $unwind: '$sanctions' },
            { $match: { 'sanctions.type': 'MUTE' } },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: '$sanctions._id',
                    user: { $first: '$user' },
                    expiry: { $max: '$sanctions.expiry' }
                }
            }
        ]).exec();
```

The problem is that it retrieves all the mutes of all the users. I would like to retrieve only the latest (the latest expiry date)

I would like the following return (only one record per users):

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("614b5db2c94fec299d85c648"), "user" : "username", "expiry" : ISODate("2021-10-15T17:00:38.461Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61646db623894d61e8dc8afe"), "user" : "username1", "expiry" : ISODate("2021-10-20T17:00:38.461Z") }
```

Any ideas ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your query is you are grouping by `$sanctions._id` but `_id` field is not into `sanctions` object, is in the parent one. Then is like you are grouping by `null`.

So you have to modify the `$group` stage like this:

```
$group: {
  _id: "$_id",
  user: {
    $first: "$user"
  },
  expiry: {
    $max: "$sanctions.expiry"
  }
}
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1mvwwft4fnl)

Where you get the desired value:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("614b5db2c94fec299d85c648"),
    "expiry": ISODate("2021-10-15T17:00:38.461Z"),
    "user": "username"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("61646db623894d61e8dc8afe"),
    "expiry": ISODate("2021-10-20T17:00:38.461Z"),
    "user": "username1"
  }
]
```